# Indesign script to copy from clipboard to story

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

I know `app.paste();` method dumps the contents of the clipboard at the spot where the cursor is currently. However, I want to define the location via a variable such as this:

```
myStory = app.activeDocument.stories[1];
```

And I want to dump the contents of the clipboard in that story as defined by the variable `myStory`. Is it possible? How?

Comment: Why does this question deserve a downvote?

Comment: Didnt dowvote, but i could hazard that your question may come as a bit unresearched. The question in my mind its ok tough it may be more of stuff for stackoverflow instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cant insert it into the story, but you can use insertionPoints like this:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var ip = doc.stories[1].insertionPoints[0];
app.select(ip, SelectionOptions.REPLACE_WITH);
app.paste();
```